# How to export this PDF figure with a small size

Tags: export

I want to export a PDF figure with the following codes, but the size of the PDF is too big, about 1.5M. I hope the size can be around 100k. I have tried for a long time but can not find a good  solution.  Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated!

```
\[Rho]2plus = {{0.2011205485336045077` + 
 1.`*^-6 I, -0.017422322154311026` - 
 0.508770348467936524` I, -0.01627481119236278` - 
 0.009599125271231317` I, 
0.00012377921551508936` - 
 0.0001037303194895626` I}, {-0.317422322154311026` + 
 0.008770348467936524` I, 0.5253584399150775` + 1.`*^-6 I, 
0.1810835129135062` - 0.050379441418388037` I, 
0.012122030783398718` - 
 0.00011053335415397864` I}, {-0.01627481119236278` + 
 0.009599125271231317` I, 
0.4810835129135062` + 0.050379441418388037` I, 
0.07251617971431137` + 1.`*^-6 I, 
0.011027619410833644` + 
 0.00549701145732366` I}, {0.20012377921551508936` + 
 0.0001037303194895626` I, 
0.012122030783398718` + 0.00011053335415397864` I, 
0.011027619410833644` - 0.00549701145732366` I, 
0.001004831837006529` + 1.`*^-6 I}};

\[Rho]2minus = {{0.005277185010322719` + 1.`*^-6 I, 
0.0010040157957586214` + 
 0.04371079428674348` I, -0.09005650743684472643` - 
 0.046221573555130006` I, -0.003643884304307673` - 
 0.001085378855037156` I}, {0.2010040157957586214` - 
 0.24371079428674348` I, 
0.0131515781501287` + 1.`*^-6 I, -0.1857896769310657` + 
 0.01114973388880884` I, 
0.008915832323651186` + 
 0.03176372686431984` I}, {0.5005650743684472643` + 
 0.046221573555130006` I, -0.0857896769310657` - 
 0.01114973388880884` I, 
0.07651833701845997` + 1.`*^-6 I, -0.0025963451307736015` - 
 0.034899274546212444` I}, {-0.003643884304307673` + 
 0.001085378855037156` I, 
0.208915832323651186` - 
 0.23176372686431984` I, -0.0025963451307736015` + 
 0.034899274546212444` I, 0.005052899821088675` + 1.`*^-6 I}};



figplus=GraphicsRow[
DiscretePlot3D[#@\[Rho]2plus[[i, j]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1., 1., .8}, ExtentSize -> 0.5, 
  PlotRange -> {{.5, 4.5}, {.5, 4.5}, {-.5, .526}}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &), 
  ExtentElementFunction -> "ProfileCube", 
  Ticks -> {{{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}, {4, "D"}}, {{1, 
      "E"}, {2, "F"}, {3, "G"}, {4, "H"}}, Automatic}, 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}, 
  FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  Boxed -> True] & /@ {Re, Im} , ImageSize -> 500 ];



figminus =GraphicsRow[DiscretePlot3D[#@\[Rho]2minus[[i, j]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1., 1., .8}, ExtentSize -> 0.5, 
  PlotRange -> {{.5, 4.5}, {.5, 4.5}, {-.5, .523}}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &), 
  ExtentElementFunction -> "ProfileCube", 
  Ticks -> {{{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}, {4, "D"}}, {{1, 
      "E"}, {2, "F"}, {3, "G"}, {4, "H"}}, Automatic}, 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}, 
  FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  Boxed -> True] & /@ {Re, Im} , ImageSize -> 500 ];
gg = Grid[{{figminus}, {figplus}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
Export["Fig8.pdf", gg, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: The statement `ExtentElementFunction` adds additional information to the plot:

> ExtentElementFunction  is an option to DiscretePlot and DiscretePlot3D
> that gives a function to use to generate the primitives for rendering
> each extent element.

If you need this statement you can save allways in an other format:

    Export["Fig8.pdf", gg]
    Export["Fig8.jpg", gg]

PDF ~ 1.5 MB versus jpg ~ 60 KB, 

or leave out `ExtentElementFunction -> "ProfileCube"`

Comment: Please take a few minutes to format your post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting. You can also take a look at your previous question that have already been edited by experienced community members.

Comment: You need to reformat your question, but definitely changing `ImageResolution` to less than 600 can significantly reduce the final size. Generally 300 is enough.

Comment: The code you posted is unreadable and un-copyable.  Please fix the formatting.  Editing help is on the right of the edit box.  More help is available by pressing the (?) button in the edit toolbar.

Comment: @Lou, I do not want to save the figure as "jpg" format. I need a PDF figure, so as to keep the vector properties of the letters in the figure. Also I need to keep the "ProfileCube", because it looks very beautiful. @ Mahdi, If I use 300 as the ImageResolution, the size is still 1.6M

Comment: I have improved the format. Thank you all for your kind help.

Comment: @user14634, please post your improvement as answer.

Comment: @Lou, But it is not an answer. I need a small size vector-maintained PDF figure.

Answer (score 1):

For this answer, I accept no praise. All positive remarks toll @Jens. This [link](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html) shows us a fantastic strategy (see Section: Exporting 3D graphics as PDF/EPS).

just include ... as part of the Prolog:

```
Map[SetOptions[#, 
    Prolog -> {{EdgeForm[], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
       Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> #] &[{{0, 0}, {1, 
          0}, {1, 1}}]}}] &, {Graphics3D, ContourPlot3D, 
   ListContourPlot3D, ListPlot3D, Plot3D, ListSurfacePlot3D, 
   ListVectorPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D, RegionPlot3D, RevolutionPlot3D,
    SphericalPlot3D, VectorPlot3D, DiscretePlot3D}];
```

and for fine-tuning:

```
Export["Fig8.pdf", gg, ImageResolution -> 288]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. But the letters "0.5, 0.0, -0.5, A, B, C, D, ..." in exported "Fig8.pdf" figure are no longer in vector format.  The letters cannot be chosen and edited by Adobe acrobat. I need  vector format for the letters.

Comment: @user14634 Good to know. Why should one do that? What's the point?

Comment: This figure will be inserted in a paper. If we keep the letters in vector format, the printed figure in the paper will be very clear (high resolution). Otherwise, the  figure is not clear, and the quality of the paper will be decreased.

Comment: @user14634 Oh! Paper, Why should one chose and edit letters by Adobe, save it by highres algo to a scientific Paper (presumably)? Are you using LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, the figure will be used in a scientific paper and will be edited by Latex. What is the meaning of "highres algo"? means high resolution algorithm? Would you please help me by saving this PDF figure with a small size? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user14634 If you persist in this strategy, your options are limited. Attempt an optimization with an Adobe product or another optimizer. Good luck.

Comment: I hope this problem can be solved within Mathematica.